# Use switch case to call php function

Tags: php, function, get, switch-statement

I have an ajax call that passes variables into the GET, this works fine as the echoes in comments appear fine however the echoes in the addProduct function do not get echoed even though i've passed the variables as arguments.

```
 $func = $_GET ['func'];

    $name =  $_GET ['name'];
    $desc = $_GET ['desc'];
    $photo = $_GET ['photo'];
    $price = $_GET ['price'];
    $cat =  $_GET ['cat'];

//These work fine
    //echo "add";
    //echo $name;
    //echo $desc;
    //echo $photo;
    //echo $price;
    //echo $cat;

    switch ($func) {
        case "add"     :  addProduct($name, $desc, $photo, $price, $cat);
        break;
        case "edit"    :  editProduct();
        break;
        case "remove"  :  editProduct();
        break;
    };

    function addProduct($name, $desc, $photo, $price, $cat) {
        echo "add";
        echo $name;
        echo $desc;
        echo $photo;
        echo $price;
        echo $cat;

    }
```

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($func)`

Comment: Do you get at least the `add` echoed? If not, then your function isn't being called at all, and you need to look at what `$func` really contains when that happens, e.g. `var_dump($func)`

Comment: "string(7) "addname""

Comment: @user3105607 There you go... edit `case "add":` to `case "addname":`

Comment: change case to "addname"

Comment: `'addname' != 'add'`. Why is the variable returning 'addname'?

Answer (score 2):

From reading the comments, I think you forgot a `&` in your url.

Instead of what you probably have:

```
myurl.com?func=addname=name&desc=desc&photo=photo
```

You need to use:

```
myurl.com?func=add&name=name&desc=desc&photo=photo
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a silly error in my AJAX call. I had written a variable twice. Using [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) helped!
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `switch` statement is not correctly entering the right `case`, so therefore your `addProduct` method is never called.

You will need to ensure that `$func == 'add'` so it enters the `add` case and calls the method.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code. It prints as expected if $func = 'add'. Check $_GET['func'].